# Snowflake View nested calculation

Tags: sql, view, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have to build a view by fetching data from 7-8 tables and then there are field which are calculated from other calculated fields. For example first calculation is if(indicator=‘H’, amount*20, amount) as deliAmt. And then
If(isnull(deliAmt),0 else deliAmt)

This is just an example but for this view i have 5-6 such calculations required.

Also the final view has around 7-8 main tables and other tables for these fetching columns for these calculations. In tolal there will be 57 columns finally.

Please guide what is the best approach to implement this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To write a view that selects data from 7-8 tables, write the SQL the select from 7-8 table and put it "in a view".

But the other part of you question of how to do IF like logic is to use in Snowflake the [IFF](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/iff.html) operator thus your example `if(indicator=‘H’, amount*20, amount) as deliAmt`

would be written

```
IFF(indicator=‘H’, amount*20, amount) as deliAmt
```

and `If(isnull(deliAmt),0 else deliAmt)` would be:

```
IFF(isnull(deliAmt), 0, deliAmt)
```

of which can also be done via [ZEROIFNULL](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/zeroifnull.html) like:

```
ZEROIFNULL(deliAmt)
```

Comment: Hey Thanks for the Answer, so I understand this is the way my query should like?                         Select t1.a,t2.b,t3.a, ZEROIFNULL(IFF(indicator=‘H’, amount*20, amount)) as Final_Amount from table1 t1 left outer join ........................ Did I understand it correctly?

Comment: @user16052342 yes, that seems about correct. Which is to say yes that is how you would do the `ZEROIFNULL`, and I assume correct for the join part.